# Button padding in Chrome

Tags: html, css, padding

I want to do the kind of menu, where when you hover the item, it get's the same color as the actual page.
e.g. like here http://www.css3.info/

It works fine with Mozilla, but in Chrome I always get a very thin line above the div, so the transition is not fluent. I have set all paddings to 0px.

The style for button looks like this:

```
button
{            
  background: #fff;   
  font-size: 14px;   
  color: #555;   
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

and for the div

```
.main_div
{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#d0f0f6;
  text-align:left;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Post up your HTML code please :) - For the navigation.

Comment: maybe you have to increase the height on hover & give z-index to the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on a guess here due to the lack of HTML markup but:

```
.button
{            
  background: #fff;   
  font-size: 14px;   
  color: #555;   
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px; //Note added line here
}
```

If you could add more precise markup I could help further

Comment: thanks. kind of works (when I sen marin-top: -2 for the div), but the problem is, that in mozzila it goes a bit under the buttons. I can get over it, but I'll wait a bit if any other answer turn up.

Comment: @Tom83B Yeah that was the effect I expected it to have, can you post some HTML code up please? Even making a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of it would be great! Just the navigation (whole menu if possible)

Comment: <div class="menu_div">
      <button class="button">Click Me!</button>
      <button href="hra2.html" class="button">Click Me!</button></div> It looked like this. I've actually already solved it. Just replaced button for a and used display: block. Really thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that this'll solve your problem, but for those with button padding issues, in general, it might be to do with box-sizing:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

At least for Chrome, button elements are given a default of:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

So any width/height set will be the actual visible width/height, with any padding/border taking up space within that width/height.
This is different to most other elements, where the default is visible width equals width + padding + borders. (This is box-sizing: content-box;).